# Coordinator Layout with Frame Layout Height Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-framelayout

Height of frame layout exceeds it's parent (i.e. Coordinator Layout), and overlaps the bottom navigation view. I need to make height as max as it's parent.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.appshah.noircaesarhomeversion.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bottomTabColor"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottomTabColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_tab_states"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need to restrict Frame Layout above Bottom navigation view.